# This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key UILabel

Tags: objective-c

In my plist, there are string typed items. Some values for the code named items are A00.0 , A00.1 etc. I try to display these in TableView with CustomCell.In CustomCell, the label is codeLabel. Code gives error for codeLabel but not giving error for nameLabel.

When I run the code it gives me this message:

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key codeLabel.

Here is my code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol CustomCellDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)updateInfo:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;

@end

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *codeLabel, *nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath *indexPath;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<CustomCellDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

I tried this but didn't work:

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell{
     UILabel *codeLabel,*nameLabel;
}
```

How can I solve this problem for codeLabel? Thank you.

[image: xib]

Comment: Could you show us a screen shot of your Instrument environment of your custom cell ?
A thing that could be : You set the File's Owner class to CustomCell instead of doing it with your graphic object Cell...

Comment: How are you loading the custom cell? Did you set the File's Owner of your custom class in the interface builder. Sometimes this error is there when you have created a connection with that name and then deleted the object but the connection tries to set the object.

Comment: I couldn't attach an image. Sorry. I created outlets(codelabel,namelabel) in CustomCell.h. In xib view I drop down them on the label objects. So you say that it gives problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try declaring codeLabel and nameLabel in two separate properties?

And if that doesn't do it, check your labels connections and make sure they don't have a connection to a property that doesn't exist, or exists twice.